# HorizontalScrollView to prevent Out of Memory issue and load fast images in horizontal scroll in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I want to add lazy loading feature to HorizontalScrollView, 
Linearlayout as a child and i am addding to linear layout, I want that when image view is out of focus then in horizontal scroll view that can not load but when its come in visible area it will load images(Kind of lazy loading).

I want that because bitmap attached to the child view can be recycled and create bitmap again when child view is visible but the question is how can I make such custom view. I can not use gallery view because it does not solve my purpose I saw that viewgroup has feature of dispatchingViewVisibility and dispatchOnDraw but not sure how to use that with HorizontalScrollView.?

I just want to load fast images in horizontal scroll view which I am adding pro grammatically and prevent OOM issue.

Any suggestion and help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) , or use a horizontalListView as created by others ([here](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.co.il/2012/04/creating-horizontal-listview-in-android.html) ,[here](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34), and [here](https://github.com/vieux/Android-Horizontal-ListView) for example) .

in the adapter , set an asyncTask to load the info , and if you get to go to a new view that was recycled , cancel the asyncTask it had so that it will start a new one .

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but here I am looking for n no of horizontal scroll bar in vertical scroll and require to be implemented in horizontal scroll it self because everything I have setup programatically to add dynamic view in horizontally so if you can provide solution in horizontal scroll itself that would be highly recomanded

Comment: I choose `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` but just can't solve OOM issue. So sad.

Answer (score 0):

try to use ViewPager. Acts like HorizontalScrollView but uses adapter as child views source.

Comment: Same solution as what I wrote?